# Error for abstract class: class, interface, or enum expected

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, abstract

I have been running into this quite odd (but rather common issue among stackoverflow) issue with my abstract class. I am trying to implement this sort of hierarchy:

Abstract Shape, class Circle, class Rectangle, class Square

Circle and Rectangle inherit from abstract Shape, and square inherits from Rectangle. I have also made a ShapeContainer class with an ArrayList and a couple of methods. Also I have added a TestShapeContainer class to test these features. Below is the related code (since there are lots of code I will try to put what is relevant) :

ABSTRACT SHAPE:

```
public abstract Shape
{
  public double getArea();

  public String toString();
}
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Error at Shape.java Error: class, interface, or enum expected (lines: 1, 3, 5, 6) at abstract Shape
```

CLASS SHAPECONTAINER:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ShapeContainer
{
  //  PROPERTIES  //
  private ArrayList<Shape> container;

  // CONSTRUCTORS //
  public ShapeContainer()
  {
    container = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  //    METHODS   //
  public void add(Shape s)
  {
    container.add(s);
  }

  public double getArea(int index)
  {
    return container.get(index).getArea();
  }

  public int getSize()
  {
    return container.size();
  }
}
```

I have the corresponding getArea and toString methods in Circle, Rectangle and Square.

Anything I am missing? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: it should be: public abstract class Shape

Comment: Oopsy daisy ty very much I think I should take notes during class hehe

Answer (score 3):

You forgot `class` keyword:

```
public abstract class Shape {
  public double getArea();

  public String toString();
}
```

And you will need to define your methods to be abstract like this:

```
public abstract class Shape {
  public abstract double getArea();

  public abstract String toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) I guess ı should not have tried to remember everything from the class without looking at notes :) Ty again